# Не работают медиа-запросы в css

Tags: css, google-chrome

Задаю в head

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

В css-файл

```
@media all and (max-width: 1050px){

header ul.main_menu{
    margin-left: 7vw;
}

header ul.main_menu li{
    padding-left: 1.5vw;
}

} /* max-width: 1050px */
```

В Chrome  в режиме разработки отзывчивого дизайна не работает. С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 1):

Указанный вами код работает так, как и положено.
Он применяется только при ширине экрана меньше или равной 1050px.

Вот пример для демонстрации:

```css
@media all and (max-width: 1050px) {
  body {
    background-color: maroon;
  }
}
```

Вот скриншот работы указанного сниппета (с мета-тегами) в режиме разработки Chrome:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я рекомендую вам проверить указанный путь к css-файлу.

Comment: да, на телефоне оно видит это. Но как сделать, чтоб и при уменьшении окна браузера видело?

Comment: @ДимаШевченко и при уменьшении окна видит. Попробуйте развернуть на весь экран сниппет. Нажмите выполнить код, а потом на ссылку "На всю страницу". Фон пропадет.